# How to disallow git commit -a option

Tags: git

we are a group of developers working on the same set of files. I want to make sure that no one does a git commit -a  -m or git commit -am

The developers including me have this bad habbit of `git commit -am/ -a -m` and we have a lot of conf files specific to the machine that get committed everytime. I could ask us all to use --assume-unchanged but I want to make the developers not be able to use -a flag at all

Can I hack somehow to achieve this.?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but if the intent is specifically to guard against committing conf files, then perhaps creating a `.gitignore` may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to solve this problem differently:

1. use a [.gitignore file](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) to specifically exclude files which must not be committed or
2. use a [pre-commit hook](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) to automatically reject commits which look like they were made with -a.

When you insist on disabling the -a flag: well, git is open source. Finding and disabling the code which reads the -a command line parameter and recompiling shouldn't be that hard. But that would mean you would have to do it again whenever a new version of git is released, so I would really advise against that.

Comment: Even I am against rewriting git. I will try to learn to write precommit hook. ANy good resources?

Comment: @RanjithR You can start by looking at the `.git/hooks/*.sample` files in any git repository. But I don't know whether `-a` doesn't stage all modified files _before_ calling that hook

Comment: I think a .gitignore file would be the better solution. It would still allow people to save time by using -a, but prevent them from committing any machine-specific files.

Comment: The problem is .gitignore will completely ignore that file. Sometimes we add things to the conf file and we will need to commit them. Then everyone is informed to take a backup and we merge them with care.

Comment: @RanjithR So does your acceptance mean you made a pre-commit hook? If so please edit it into the answer for others to see

Comment: No. I initially decided to use pre commit hook. Hence I accepted the answer. But the problem was solved after a strong management session and now everyone uses git commit -m aliased as gcm.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a wrapper `git` script that checks whether the command is `commit` and has the `-a` flag set. Then you can either drop that and pass everything else on to the actual `git`, or prompt "Bad User! Bad!". Put that script in the path before the actual git path or create an alias for your `gitwrap`.

@PiotrZierhoffer found this:

> An example for that is here:
>   [Disable -m in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157326/disable-m-in-git/22160650#22160650)

Comment: This is a great solution. I added an implementation as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This habit also leads to annoying issues with submodules and pre commit code formatting. A config option to disallow `-a` would be perfect. Second best is implementing the suggestion given by @TobiasKienzler:

```
git() {
    # specifically disallow "git commit -a", nothing more
    if [[ $1 == 'commit' && $2 == '-a' ]]
    then
        echo "Bad User! Bad!"
        return
    fi
    command git "$@"
}
```

Easy to circumvent, but that is a feature.